# Hiercube bugs - Out of Memory

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, cube

i'm using delphi 7 to run the hiercube version 4.32. When i retrieve the data, the pc memory keep increasing until occur 'Out of Memory' bug. I suspect the cache of memory did not clear when retrieve the data from hiercube, so when i retrieve data for 2nd or third times then it occur 'Out of Memory' error. Any idea to solve this 'Out of Memory' problem?

Comment: usually such errors are caused by fragmentation combined with code requiring large contiguous blocks of memory. Do you have the source for this component? Have you spoken to the vendors?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious fix (work-around?) is to get more RAM. 1 GB is a bit on the low side these days, especially when 4 GB is at around the $100 mark.

Comment: 1GB ram is for my local pc, i test in server (which have larger ram) also got same problem. I suspect the cache of memory did not clear when retrieve the data from hiercube, so when i retrieve data for 2nd or third times then it occur 'Out of Memory' error.

Comment: Then the other work-around is to run hiercube in subprocesses that only run it once each.

Comment: @David: No dispute there. Of course, the sledgehammer may just be the handiest object in easy reach.

Answer (score 0):

Use FastMM as your memory manager, then either (or both):

- make it report memory leaks on shutdown
- use the memory monitor example form at run-time

Then start investigating the memory leak.

--jeroen